# Sudoers file shows effect only after touch - w.r.t the usb device

Tags: command-line, sudo

Suoders file contains this line, where abc is the username:

```
abc ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /dev/sdb1
```

My problem is that when I plugin a usb, I can't execute the command `sudo cat /dev/sdb1` without password.

Then I do `sudo touch /etc/sudoers`. Then when I re-execute the previous command, it does not require the password.

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for abc on xyz-134:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User abc may run the following commands on xyz-134:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /dev/sdb1
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

What is causing this and what can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you *really* doing `touch /etc/sudoers` - or `sudo touch /etc/sudoers`?

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l`, please.

Comment: The `(ALL: ALL) ALL` comes after the rule you added, so it takes precedence. Add your rule after it.

Comment: @muru I request you to explain the proper syntax as an answer.

Comment: There is no syntax problem here. You have to find where the second rule comes from, and add your NOPASSWD rule after it. That's all.

Comment: FWIW the reason you're not asked for your password after running `sudo touch /etc/sudoers` is simply that your credentials have been cached (nothing to do with the `touch` command specifically)